# Store comment and post after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I have a article/comments controller. When a user submits a comment and not logged in I want it to store in a session. After success login I want to create the stored comment.

What is the best way to do this?

btw: I got nested routes. articles => comments

so far i got:

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
      def create
       if current_user
         create...
       else
        session[:comment] = params
        redirect_to login_path
       end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preliminary note:

Instead of storing the params hash it is much better practice (and makes more sense) to create  a comment that is not in a published state and store the ID in the session.

When you go to authenticate a user and the authentication is valid you can simply toggle that comment to be published using something like

```
comment = Comment.find(session[:comment])
comment.update_attribute(:published, true)
```

Alternatively you could also redirect the user to a queue of their unpublished comments (you likely already redirect them to a dashboard page or something of the sorts).